# Why can't I see comment on column?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I Can't see comment on column.

I think everything is done well, but I don't get what I want

```
create table TRANSAKCIJE (
tx_id number generated by default as identity,
acc_id number,
tx_date date,
tx_iznos number,

constraint fk_accounts
foreign key(acc_id)
references accounts(acc_id)
);                    

comment on column transakcije.tx_id 
is 'This is transaction ID';

comment on column transakcije.acc_id
is 'This is accounts ID';

comment on column transakcije.tx_date
is 'This is transaction DATE';

comment on column transakcije.tx_iznos
is 'This is transaction AMOUNT';

commit;

desc transakcije;
```

I got this output:

```
Name     Null?    Type   
-------- -------- ------ 
TX_ID    NOT NULL NUMBER 
ACC_ID            NUMBER 
TX_DATE           DATE   
TX_IZNOS          NUMBER
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query Data Dictionary view `USER_COL_COMMENTS` to display comments on the columns of the tables and views owned by the current user, such as using

```
select column_name, comments
  from user_col_comments
 where table_name = 'TRANSAKCIJE'
```

If you need comments added directly on tables you can use `USER_TAB_COMMENTS`

<kbd>[Demo](https://rextester.com/VIUA88882)</kbd>

Comment: The same problem

Comment: @petar excuse me, I missed the part the comments are not on the table but on columns. So, use `user_col_comments` instead(I edited the answer).

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I can not get comments

Comment: I get 0 comments

Comment: @petar I added a demo.